# Как вычислить растояние которое объекту нужно пройти по NavMesh для достижения некой точки?

Tags: unity3d

Есть несколько точек к которым нужно пройти по навмэшу, нужно вычислить к которой путь будет самым коротким. Есть ли команда для этого? Впринципе это вся суть вопроса.

Comment: `path.corners[]` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath.html

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо yaroslav за ответ, но уточню для тех у кого будет такая же проблема, но они не поняли ответа Ярослава. Через CalculatePath вычисляем путь и получаем доступ к точкам через path.corners[] и через цыкл складываем дистанцию между ними.